# With Ajax and OpenID connect, how can I get the part of the URL past the '#'

Tags: ajax, openid-connect

I want to use Ajax authenticated by OpenID-Connect in a standard way. When I look at the URL string returned by OpenID-Connect it has all the important information after the '#' character. The url is coming back like "http://www.example.com/#auth=&token_type=aaaaaa&id_token=bbb...".

Unfortunately, Ajax doesn't see the URL past the '#' so I can't get at the authentication information.  For example, in "http://www.example.com/#string1?string2" appears in Ajax as "http://www.example.com/".

What trick can I use to make the part of the URL past the '#' available in my Ajax single page application?

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can use `location.hash.substring(1)` to get the part after the hash.

Comment: IFF there was something there, I could get them. The problem I am describing is that the string after the '#' is not there once the string gets passed to Ajax.

Comment: then something is stripping it before it hits your Javascript most probably there's some form of redirect in between, served through your backend